# Having trouble building Android Studio project

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am taking a unit for mobile computing in Uni and I am new to Android Studio and building mobile app stuff. Feeling desperate :'( 
When I try to run the project on android emulator, the following error occurred. Any idea how to fix :'(

Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/orm/SchemaGenerator;

Here is the what is displayed on Console after I run with stacktrace, in case you ask

Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.
If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to /Users/EfanDYH/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle.
If you are not using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or local.properties to remove this warning.

.....

Comment: Are you using the NDK and is it installed? `Tools->Android->SDK Manager->SDK Tools`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to your app gradle file and put   **multiDexEnabled true** like below

`defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}`

Answer (score 0):

restart the studio and then clean the project in build tab/menu